# Typescript: Is it possible to add extension method to type union such as T | null | undefined?

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

I'm learning typescript language features and recently i have figured out how to write extension methods for built-in classes (Array, String, Object, etc) and external modules. However, I still can't understand if it's possible to extend types, like type unions, intersections and other stuff.

For example, sometimes I get variables typed as `T | null` after calling some methods:

```js
interface Book { title: string, authors: Author[] }
const books: Book[] = ...
books.
    // some operations
    .find(item => item)
    // right here i want to call method
```

The `Array.prototype.find` method returns `T | null` and i want to convert it to [`Optional<T>`](https://github.com/bromne/typescript-optional) on fly, but it's impossible. Of course, I can just wrap the entire methods chain into `Optional.ofNullable(/* huge code fragment here */)`. That looks so ugly.

What I've done so far is trying to add extension method to `Object` interface and restrict `this` with type annotation.

```js
declare global {
    interface Object {
        toOptional<T>(this: T | null): Optional<T>;
    }
}

// Implementation of the method above

books
    .find(book => Boolean(book.title) && book.authors.length > 1)
    .toOptional()
    .map(book => book.title)
    .ifPresent(console.log);
```

It doesn't work. I expect this code to log any title that has more than one author, but it won't even compile. To be honest, Typescript does not allow to engage *any* method on type unions like these. Result: `Object is possibly null`.

Comment: JavaScript (and TypeScript) doesn't have extension methods - what you're probably talking about here is modifying the prototype of Object which is normally something to avoid. The standard ways you would do this in JavaScript are still valid here such as a statement like `book && book.title` or alternatively you could use `filter()` rather than find and this will simply end up with an empty array so your `map` to retrieve the title won't encounter an undefined.

Comment: `undefined.method()` will always blow up at runtime, so your only chance here is to prevent `undefined` from showing up in the first place.  If you're going to override anything it should be a replacement for `Array.prototype.find()` that returns `Optional<T>`.  I would suggest subclassing `Array` and not adding into `Array` if you're doing that.    So instead of `const books: Book[] = ...` you have `const books: MyArray<Book> = ...` and you call `books.findOptional(book => ...).map...`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I would like to share my initial thoughts about declaring and using extension methods on union types here:

> When you use a union type like `string | number`, you will be able to use only the interface that is shared by all the types in the union. If you want to use an extension method for such a union type, I guess you will have to implement your extension method (with compatible signatures) on all those types separately. In this case an extension method on the `String` interface and also an extension method on the `Number` interface. This way you can also implement separate logic that applies to those specific types. The correct extension method will be called automatically.
>
> When not all types in your union implement the extension method, like `string | null | undefined`, you will have to include proper type guards in your code to make sure that you are not calling (extension) methods on types that do not implement it. Otherwise you will get a compilation error. That would just be default TypeScript behavior, as I see it; no difference between extension methods and native methods.
>
> When you want to call (extension) methods on generic types like `<T>`, you have to make sure that those generic types will inherit from types that implement those (extension) methods. This would also be default TypeScript behavior; no difference here between extension methods and native methods as well.

Having said that, I want to remark that there is a very vivid discussion about the use of extension methods. They can potentially conflict with existing or future (native) implementations, so be very careful with them.

Now, let's look at your issue and the examples you provided.

Hmmm. For a solution to your example code, it seems that you do not need custom extension methods at all, I think. If you just want to show the titles of all the books that have more than one author, you could use this code instead:

```ts
books
  .filter(book => book.title && book.authors.length > 1)
  .forEach(book => console.log(book.title));
```

(Note that the `Array`'s `filter` method returns an array containing all the elements that satisfy the provided testing function, but the `find` method only returns the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.)

If this simple solution does not fit your actual scenarios in production (perhaps because your example was greatly simplified) and you still want to use a clean fluent interface as much as possible, you might want to consider the following:

- Create (extension) methods that always return valid object instances themselves (never `null` or `undefined`) and fall back to some predefined default instance when necessary. You could use an additional parameter in your (extension) methods that take the default instance you want to return instead of `null` or `undefined`.
- Put intermediate results that can possibly be `null` or `undefined` (for example the result of the `find` call) in a temporary variable. Continue your fluent coding on that variable if its value is valid. That should avoid your dreaded wrapping in parentheses:

```ts
 // Instead of this:

books
    .find(...)
    .authors.forEach(author => console.log(author));

// you could write:

const book = books
    .find(...);

book && book
    .authors.forEach(author => console.log(author));
```

Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible natively. The only workaround I can think of (apart from wrapping your whole chain) is overwriting the `find` method to return an `Optional<T>` instead of `T | null`. I'd really not recommend to do that though, since you'd change the implementation for  the whole page. So if libraries depend on `find` returning `T | null` and not an `Optional<T>`, it will give you problems.

You could create your own implementation of `Array` to mitigate that problem, but gives you a slight overhead of transforming existing Arrays to your implementation.

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array {
  public find(cb:any):Optional<T> {
    return Optional.ofNullable(super.find(cb));
  }
}

interface Book { title: string, authors: Author[] }
const books: MyArray<Book> = new MyArray(); // Create clean instance

const booksNormal: Book[] = [/* Some Values */];
const books2: MyArray<Book> = new MyArray(...booksNormal); // Transform existing, "normal" array

books.
    // some operations
    .find(item => item)
    .map(book => book.title)
    .ifPresent(console.log);
```

Comment: That's so sad. I think the most elegant solution is to add the brand new extension method for `Array<T>` interface like `findOptional(predicate: T => boolean): Optional<T>;`. I wont close this thread, because I hope someone will find better solution.

Comment: You can do that in a derived class as well - just rename the `find()` method in `MyArray` to `findOptional()`. I'd advise against extending the native `Array` directly (as in `Array.prototype.findOptional = ...`). This *could* introduce hard to debug bugs in your application (imagine you add this method and a library does the same but with another signature - or the same signature but different results).

Answer (score -1):

Typescript is actually saving your implementation, which might result in a null pointer exception. It doesn't make sense to use T | null in a chain.

And I think you are mistaken .filter with .find? Since you treat result of find as an array?

```js
const books = [
  { title: 'This is a title', authors: [1] }, 
  { title: 'This is another title', authors: [1,2]}
]

books
  .filter(book => Boolean(book.title) && book.authors.length > 1)
  .map(book => book.title)
  .forEach(console.log)
```

Even if you'd like to add an extension to an already existing method, the implementation will remain same. You can pass compile time but in runtime you might end up with null pointer exception.

Comment: No, I'm not. `Optional<T>` has method `map` that changes the item if it's not null. Then i wanted to log that to console.
"It doesn't make sense to use T | null in a chain."
Yes, but in JavaScript i think its impossible to invoke any method if `this` equals to `null`.